# In flume, how can i source multiple and dynamic real time files

Tags: flume

I have a program which runs every  minute and uses STRACE command to make multiple log files simultaneously.
For example In first  run - It might start tracing 10 processes with a log file name as unique PIDS, this will keep running till the entire stracing completes. In mean time second run would start, where it might start tracing few more processes ID's.
Now i want to continuosly stream all these STRACE logs to another server using flume. 
I tried using spool but, since i have dynamic multiple real time files so, this was a bad option.
I thougt of using exec (tail) but as described the files names are multiple and quite dynamic so, could not figure out the best way to configure source.
Apprecite suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation I had experienced.

At that time,

Exec Source was used and custom program was developed as command of Exec Source.
That program monitored specific directory and if appropriate filename was detected with regexpr, created thread to read it and wrote contents into stdout like tail.

I am also curious about is there any easier way to solve that kind of things. :)